# Java Regex pattern not matching

Tags: java, regex

I have a .txt file and at the end there is a marker "Home" and I want to take all text after the Home marker till the end of file.
But in few cases I have a situation that after the text that I want to take I have several empty lines (more than 3) and some text that I don't need.
SO I need the regex that take all the text after Home marker but if there will be empty lines 3 or more it will stop.
Here is this .txt file that makes problem:

```
Home
"Empty LINE"
    some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I needsome text that I need

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"






some info that I don't need
some info that I don't need
some info that I don't need
some info that I don't need
```

And here is my code:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FILENAME)));

System.out.println(content);
    String pattern = "Home\\s(.*$)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(content);
      if (m.find( )) {

         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );

      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
```

Comment: so in this case you will take only `"Empty LINE"
    some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I needsome text that I need`

Comment: How about: `Home.*?(?=\n{3}|$)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ibSZV/1)

Comment: but when I run my code I have: NO MATCH

Comment: Use the `DOTALL` flag: `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL)`. Updated the answer @Dzbanek

Comment: **WARNING:** The text file shown in the question is *not* the actual text file OP wants to process. See OP comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270804/java-regex-patter-not-matching/44271117?noredirect=1#comment75550697_44270889) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270804/java-regex-patter-not-matching/44271117?noredirect=1#comment75550683_44271117) saying: *[ideone.com/bY1yK4](http://ideone.com/bY1yK4) here is the content of txt file*

Answer (score 0):

To get all text until you get three empty lines or the end of the file, try:

```
Home\\s(.*?)(?=\\n{3}|$)
```

- `Home\s` matches `Home` literal followed by a space `\s`
- Followed by capturing group `(.*?)` any characters (non-greedy)
- Positive Lookahead `(?=\\n{3}|$)` to check if it is followed by 3 empty lines `\n{3}` or by end of file `$`

Also, you need to use the `DOTALL` flag, so that dot `.` matches line delimiters too.

```
Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ibSZV/1/)

Here's a working [Java Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/3Cqz43)

Comment: so when I run it I have: error app crashes, I have to change to m.group(0) and then I have : Found value: whole text from file oh and it's not 3 empty lines, sometimes it's 3 sometimes more like 7

Comment: if I use this one: Home\\s(.*?)(?=\n{3}|$) and add DOTALL to pattern I have NO MATCH

Comment: Try again with updated regex in answer: `Home\\s(.*?)(?=\\n{3}|$)` so that it works with `m.group(1)` and extracts just what you need. It doesn't matter whether you have 3 or 100. The condition checks for a minimum of 3. If you want to change the minimum condition change the number `\n{3}`

Comment: yes this pattern works with your text just fine but not with text from my file

Comment: Are you sure it has a minimum of 3 empty lines after the text?

Comment: Wait @Dzbanek, try this: `Home\\s(.*?)(?=\\n{3}|(?:\\r\\n){3}|$)`. My guess is that the line delimitters are `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. You can actually check the line delimitters by accessing your file's contents while debugging

Comment: SO maybe we will take all text after Home marker till the end of file and then we replace all 3+ empty lines with text after it with " " so we remove it ? do you know how to do this ?

Comment: How much text does each new line have? One space? or more? Check directly in the original file

Comment: its like this I have a line with marker Home then a new line and after this random numer of lines with text that I want sometimes 1 , 2, 3 and end of  file OR random numer of emty lines but more than 3 and random numer of lines with text that I dont want.... I have posted just one file but I have more files. But can you tell me how to take ALL the text after Home till the end of file ? And then how to make a regex for replaceAll to find all 3+ emtylines with text after them?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will do it:

```
"(?s)(?:^|\\R)Home\\R(.*?)(?:\\R{3}|$)"
```

Explanation:

- `(?s)` - Allow the `.` specified later to match line terminators ([`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag).
- `(?:^|\\R)` - Match the beginning of the text or a line terminator. Note that the `\R` [linebreak matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) is used so Windows line terminators will be matched correctly.
- `Home\\R` - Match the text `Home` and a line terminator.
- `(.*?)` - Match and [capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical) the desired the text, ending as soon as the following match pattern identifies the end of desired text ([reluctant quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc)).
- `(?:\\R{3}|$)` - Match 3 line terminators or the end of text.

*Test*

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file.txt");
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path)); // assume default character encoding

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?:^|\\R)Home\\R(.*?)(?:\\R{3}|$)").matcher(text);
if (m.find())
    System.out.printf("'%s'", m.group(1));
else
    System.out.println("** NOT FOUND **");
```

Text file is copy/paste of text from question.

*Output*

```
'"Empty LINE"
    some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I need some text that I needsome text that I need

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"

"Empty LINE"'
```

Comment: I still have no match

Comment: well I dont need those empty lines just the text some text some text....

Comment: @Dzbanek Unlike your question, the text in that link has spaces before the `Home` text, so change regex to `"(?s)(?:^|\\R)[ \t]*Home[ \t]*\\R(.*?)(?:\\R{3}|$)"`

Comment: well if you prep the file to match the pattern ...... sure it works..... but it doesn't work with my text

Comment: @Dzbanek I've done no prep. Copied the text **exactly** as you gave it in the link. Had to write it as a string literal for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the text is **exactly** as you gave it in the link (use the "copy" link in upper right). We can only work with what you tell us, so if your text is *different*, that's your problem. Sorry, I'm done wasting my time on your incomplete question. My answer works for the given text!!!